# Making SAPUI5 Application Full Screen Created on WebIde FullStack

Tags: sapui5, sap-fiori, sap-web-ide

Created apps from SAP Webide Fullstack, couldn't been full screen.

I'm writing into manifest json below codes:

```
"config": {
         "sapFiori2Adaptation": true,
            "fullWidth": true
        },
```

index.html files include below codes:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>App</title>

        <script id="sap-ui-bootstrap"
            src="../../resources/sap-ui-core.js"
            data-sap-ui-theme="sap_fiori_3"
            data-sap-ui-resourceroots='{"com.app.ZSES_APP": "./"}'
            data-sap-ui-compatVersion="edge"
            data-sap-ui-oninit="module:sap/ui/core/ComponentSupport"
            data-sap-ui-async="true"
            data-sap-ui-frameOptions="trusted">
        </script>
    </head>
    <body class="sapUiBody">
        <div data-sap-ui-component data-name="com.app.ZSES_APP" data-id="container" data-settings='{"id" : "ZSES_APP"}'></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

index html doesn't contain shell block, so i can't implement `appWidthLimited: false,` block to index.html.

How can i make full screen my ui5 application?

Please help...

Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Look in the `manifest.json` routing section and configure the application routes and the relevant views for these routes.

On the route `"pattern": "/"` View you should define the `sap.m.Shell` control as the root control for the UI5 application.

And of course on the Shell control set `appWidthLimited: false`